# django collectstatic not working with s3 backend behind nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, minio

I have a minio server as my object storage which django uses as its Static file storage (using `django-minio-storage`). I have set up an Nginx server to proxy minio. When I run the `collectstatic` command, it gets stuck in the first file and does not put the files to minio.

Here is my config:

settings.py

```py
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "minio_storage.storage.MinioMediaStorage"
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = "minio_storage.storage.MinioStaticStorage"
    MINIO_STORAGE_ENDPOINT = config("MINIO_STORAGE_ENDPOINT", "")
    MINIO_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY = config("MINIO_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY", "")
    MINIO_STORAGE_SECRET_KEY = config("MINIO_STORAGE_SECRET_KEY", "")
    MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME = config("MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME", "")
    MINIO_STORAGE_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME = config("MINIO_STORAGE_STATIC_BUCKET_NAME", "")
    MINIO_STORAGE_USE_HTTPS = True
    MINIO_STORAGE_AUTO_CREATE_MEDIA_BUCKET = True
    MINIO_STORAGE_AUTO_CREATE_STATIC_BUCKET = True
    MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_OBJECT_METADATA = {"Cache-Control": "max-age=3600"}
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 500;
}

http {

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  error_log /dev/stdout;

  gzip on;

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    ignore_invalid_headers off;
    client_max_body_size 0;

    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        
        real_ip_header X-Real-IP;

        proxy_connect_timeout 300;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;

        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";

        proxy_pass http://minio.svc:9000;
    }

}

}
```

`collectstatic -v3` result:

```
Deleting 'admin/js/actions.js'
```

the `collectstatic` command gets stuck here and does not proceed to other files.

My temporary solution was to separate the configs for putting objects and retrieving them. For putting, I use the internal address of minio and it works fine. But this solution is a bit messy and complicates future developments. I would rather find and fix the problem with the current config than investing time on separating the config for all put-object operations.